# Task does not always return upon completion

Tags: c#, task

So I am trying to build a program to control a machine. Communications with said machine is via a serial port for which I have written a driver. Continuous polling to the machine is necessary for status feedback etc. In my program I have a dedicated `ExecutionEngine()` class to handle serial send and receive. I also need to have two separate control sequences running, which I have put into methods `RunSequenceA()` and `RunSequenceB()` respectively. During normal operation, all three methods need to run until both control sequences finish, at which point the `StopSequence()` method is called. My issue is that sometimes, for whatever reason, the `StopSequence()` method is never called, leaving my `ExecutionEngine()` method in an infinite loop!

Code for `ExecutionEngine()`:

```
private static void ExecutionEngine()
{
    // Clear both lists in case they have old data
    _commandList.Clear();
    _pollingList.Clear();

    // Poll while user has not yet clicked "STOP"
    while (!_cTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // If there are commands to be sent, send them first
        if (_commandList.Count > 0)
        {
            Command[] tempCommandArray;

            lock (_commandList)
                tempCommandArray = _commandList.ToArray();

            foreach (var c in tempCommandArray)
            {
                if (_cTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    break;

                var response = SerialDriver.ComCycle(c.CommandBytes, _serialPort);
                var success = CheckErrorReturn(response, false);

                if (success)
                {
                    AddPolling(c);
                    RemoveCommand(c);
                }
            }
        }
        // Do polling operation on applicable controllers
        if (_pollingList.Count > 0)
        {
            Command[] tempPollingArray;

            lock (_pollingList)
                tempPollingArray = _pollingList.ToArray();

            foreach (var c in tempPollingArray)
            {
                if (_cTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    break;

                var response = SerialDriver.ComCycle(c.PollBytes, _serialPort);
                var success = ProcessPollReturn(response);

                if (success)
                {
                    c.FlagDone();
                    RemovePolling(c);
                }
            }
        }

        if (_commandList.Count + _pollingList.Count == 0)
        {
            // Will get stuck here if neither list gets new items added
            Console.WriteLine("Bad place");
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }

    // Cancellation has been requested
    lock (_commandList)
        _commandList.Clear();

    lock (_pollingList)
        _pollingList.Clear();

    ResetTriggers();

    var endCommand = new Command("GL_SYSCMD", 0);
    SerialDriver.ComCycle(endCommand.CommandBytes, _serialPort);
    _serialPort.Close();
    _vm.SequenceRunning = false;
    return;
}
```

Code for running sequences:

```
private static async Task RunSequencesAsync()
{
    var taskArray = new Task[2];

    var a = new Action(RunSequenceA);
    var b = new Action(RunSequenceB);

    taskArray[0] = Task.Run(a);
    taskArray[1] = Task.Run(b);

    await Task.WhenAll(taskArray).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);

    // Sometimes this never fires, WHY?
    UpdateStatus("All done!");
    StopSequence();
}

// Run A sequence
internal static void RunSequenceA()
{
    if (_sequenceA1 != null && _sequenceA1.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var s in _sequenceA1)
        {
            if (_cTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                return;

            s.Execute();

            if (s.Reference != null && TriggerStepCompleted != null)
                TriggerStepCompleted(s, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        // This part always fires
        Console.WriteLine("Sequence A finished");
        return;
    }
    else
        return;
}
```

And finally, the methods to start and stop everything:

```
private static async Task StartSequenceAsync()
{
    _serialPort.PortName = _vm.SelectedComPort;
    _serialPort.Open();
    _serialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
    _serialPort.DiscardOutBuffer();

    // Start
    _cTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    _vm.SequenceRunning = true;
    var taskArray = new Task[2];

    taskArray[0] = Task.Run(() => ExecutionEngine());
    Thread.Sleep(50);
    taskArray[1] = Task.Run(() => RunSequencesAsync());

    await Task.WhenAll(taskArray).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
}

private static void StopSequence()
{
    _cTokenSource.Cancel();
}
```

To reiterate, the problem doesn't happen every time. In fact, most times the program runs fine. It seems that problems only arise if I manually call the `StopSequence()` method half way through execution. Then it's 50/50 as to whether the problem shows up. I'm pretty sure my issue is threading related, but not sure exactly what is going wrong. Any help pointing me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does your `ExecutionEngine` method get stuck in the `while (!_cTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)` loop - is that correct?

Comment: Yes, because no new commands are being added. The idea was that once all commands have been executed from the sequences, the token would be cancelled.